# Altair Choropleth Map Encoding Dataframe Color Issue

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I'm trying to create a choropleth map with zipcode and temperature data to overly the counties, however I continue to have a Javascript error when trying to encode my data. I've looked at the github support and found that this was an issue with sometimes pulling in dataframes, but I also tried using a csv file as the datatype. It seems that the Q is not recognizing the temp column as a number?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = max_2007_df


alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color='temp:Q').transform_lookup(
    lookup='zipcode',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'zipcode', ['temp'])
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
)
```

Javascript Error: Failed to execute 'addColorStop' on 'CanvasGradient': The provided float value is non-finite.. This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the JavaScript console for the full traceback.

This is part of the max_2007_temp df

```
    zipcode temp
0   1002    33.6
1   1011    31.8
2   1013    34.1
3   1098    31.9
4   1108    34.3
5   1129    34.1
6   1453    33.3
7   1545    33.5
8   1568    33.4
9   1571    32.8
10  1603    33.5
11  1604    33.8
12  1702    35.5
13  1721    35.5
14  1746    35.5
15  1752    35.5
16  1760    35.5
17  1772    34.4
18  1773    35.5
19  1776    35.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map data you reference, `data.us_10m`, does not have any zipcode information, so it will not work to join this data on zipcode.

If you would like to make the chart you have in mind, you'll need to find a source of geographic data indexed by zipcode rather than by county.

Comment: I changed the column to strings via `max_2007_df = loc[:,'zipcode'] = max_2007_df.zipcode.apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(5))` which resulted the strings for that column but it appears I still have the same error unfortunately

Comment: if I take out the "Q" so it reads `color='temp').` I get the error: `ValueError: temp encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame.` which doesn't seem to fit with the fact it is a Dataframe, unclear if this helps